# R: How do I sum rows based on comparing columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, compare, rows

I have never asked a question before on StackOverflow, so I will try to be as clear as possible, but please give me any hints if I am doing something wrong or missing something.

I am doing research on the effect of the listening count in the early months of an artist being on a platform, on their later popularity. I want to use the information for an artist on their first three months on the platform, but only if these three months fall within the first six months. This way, you can use an even amount of information on the artists (3 months) and I don't have to wait too long before I can gather the information from the platform (6 months). I also only want to sum the counts, if the first 3 months are consecutive months.

My data looks like this:

```
my.df = data.frame(Artist = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                   Month = c('1', '9', '18', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
                   Count = c('2', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '79', '1'),
                   Index = c('1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '4'))
```

Here, the Artist of course is the artist, the months are ordered increasingly per artist, and the counts are the amount of streams an artist has in a certain month. I have added the Index variable myself. I thought this could be helpful for my question. It is an indication of the nth month in which an artist is streamed.

I basically want the code to say the following: if the first three indices of an artist occur in the first six months, then sum the counts of these first three months.

The expected output would be:

| Artist | Count |
| --- | --- |
| B | 6 |
| C | 88 |

I would expect it to include a comparison between the Index and the Month, but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tidyverse` you can do this...

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Artist) %>%     #group by artist
  filter(Month <= 6) %>%        #remove any after 6 months
  arrange(Month) %>%            #make sure sorted by Month
  slice_head(n = 3) %>%         #take the first three entries
  summarise(Count = ifelse(last(Month) == first(Month) + 2,  #if consecutive then...
                           sum(Count), NA))                  #sum of Count, otherwise NA

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Artist    Count
  <chr>     <int>
1 A            NA
2 B             6
3 C            88
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This solution worked for me. It is a smart way to get the consecutive months like this